# Using MIN(left(@prefix, 3)) in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use MIN(left) in SQL to find the prefix of an ID (for example I want UJH from UJH5433)

```
@prefix varchar(25)
AS
select  [Description]
from Prefix
where Prefix = MIN(left(@prefix, 3))
```

When I try to execute

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prefixInfo2]
```

statement, SQL doesn't seem to like the `MIN(left(@prefix, 3))` format. This is the error message I get:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Is there a way to get MIN to work?

Comment: If you run the select query outside of the procedure, does it work or do you get an error?

Comment: What is that you think `MIN` does. Because as written it doesn't make sense since it looks like @prefix is a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to get the prefix of an id is `LEFT(@id, 3)`. You don't need `MIN`.